# Laravel form have an empty value as first option of drop down

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
    $request->validate([
        'item'=>'required',
    ]);
```

Drop down list

```
{{Form::select('item', array('','1' => '1', '2' => '2'))}}
```

I set the first one to '' but it doesn't throw an error that none are selected. It is storing a blank I want the user to select a non blank option

Answer (score 0):

you can set min for validation

```
  $request->validate([
    'item'=>'required|integer',
  ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add min rule:

```
    $request->validate([
    'item'=>'required|min:1',
]);
```